# C# : How to download a file into specific file path with out using web browser

Tags: c#, hyperlink, download

I have a link ,

http://localhost/project/slide.pptx

How to download it into specific file location without using web browser.
: C#

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [**`WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri,String)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile("http://sth.com/sth.zip",
"sth.zip");
```